# Streaming protocoll for HTML5-video

Tags: video, streaming

Is there a universal streaming protocoll that both, Android and iOS devices can play, within HTML5 video objects?

It looks like even HTML5 could not "force" a universal solution to simplify publisher's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/#adaptive_streaming) and supported by the [W3 Wiki:](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/FAQs#Does_HTML5_support_adaptive.2Flive_HTTP_streaming.3F)

> Currently iOS is the only platform with adaptive streaming, supporting **Apple's own [HTTP](https://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/)** Live Streaming (HLS) protocol. Android 4 **introduced HLS support too**, but its market share is still low.